# Python replace every odd occurrence of space with "_"

Tags: python

I have the following string where I should replace every odd occurrence of space `` with `_`.

String:

`901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Local_Relay 907 46 908 51705 909 306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr`

Expected String:

`901_R 902_M 903_Picture_message 904_NA 905_F 906_Local_Relay 907_46 908_51705 909_306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr`

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show it to us!

Comment: In your input, the fields are separated by _exactly one_ space.  Can we assume that all such lines will have exactly one space?

Comment: Yes every field will be separated by one space. I tried taking the space count and also using regular expression occurrence but was not able to hit the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd probably split the string into it's constituent parts:

```
pieces = s.split()
```

Then I'd join the every element and it's appropriate neighbor with `_` and join the rest with `' '`...

```
' '.join('_'.join(pieces[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(0, len(pieces), 2))
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = '901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Local_Relay 907 46 908 51705 909 306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr'
>>> pieces = s.split()
>>> ' '.join('_'.join(pieces[i:i+2]) for i in xrange(0, len(pieces), 2))
'901_R 902_M 903_Picture_message 904_NA 905_F 906_Local_Relay 907_46 908_51705 909_306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex to handle this. You need to match a space, followed by any non-space characters, followed by another space or the end of the input. You replace the first space, but not the second one.

```
re.sub(r' ([^ ]*(?: |$))', r'_\1', text)
```

Comment: Now this works very nicely, for both an odd and even number of spaces in the input.

Comment: how do you make this work with even occurrences instead? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression with a replacement function that only actually replaces every odd call:

```
from itertools import count
import re

def replace_odd_spaces(text):
    counter = count()
    return re.sub('\s+', lambda m: match.group() if next(counter) % 2 else '_', text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> text = '901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Local_Relay 907 46 908 51705 909 306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr'
>>> replace_odd_spaces(text)
'901_R 902_M 903_Picture_message 904_NA 905_F 906_Local_Relay 907_46 908_51705 909_306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr'
```